# Django-piston: Difference between returning a queryset and a list?

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I created this simple project to illustrate my problem.

These are my models:

```
class Zoo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    zoo = models.ForeignKey(Zoo)

    def speak(zelf):
        return 'woof woof'
```

This is my base handler:

```
class ZooHandler(BaseHandler):
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'speak')
    def read(self, request):
        z = Zoo.objects.get(pk=1)

        qs = z.animal_set.all()
        return qs
```

This is the result if I don't convert the queryset to a list:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Tiger", 
        "speak": "woof woof"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Panda", 
        "speak": "woof woof"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Bear", 
        "speak": "woof woof"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Parrot", 
        "speak": "woof woof"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 5, 
        "name": "Dolphin", 
        "speak": "woof woof"
    }
]
```

This is what happens if I do convert it to a list `return list(qs)`:

```
[
    {
        "zoo_id": 1, 
        "_state": "<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x2413f90>", 
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Tiger"
    }, 
    {
        "zoo_id": 1, 
        "_state": "<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x241d590>", 
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Panda"
    }, 
    {
        "zoo_id": 1, 
        "_state": "<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x241d6d0>", 
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Bear"
    }, 
    {
        "zoo_id": 1, 
        "_state": "<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x241d750>", 
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Parrot"
    }, 
    {
        "zoo_id": 1, 
        "_state": "<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x241d7d0>", 
        "id": 5, 
        "name": "Dolphin"
    }
]
```

I lose the speak method result but gain a relational id and a _state object. Can anybody explain why this happens and how I can prevent it? This is just a test project I didn't wanna bore anybody trying to explain my real project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not actually serializing Zoo objects, but Animal objects. Piston sees that you have a queryset of Animals, and tries to find an Animal handler - not finding one, it just serializes all the built-in objects, but not the custom method.

Define an `AnimalHandler` class and move the `fields` tuple to there, and it should work.

Comment: The problem is that I am relying on a abstract model in my real code. The model type is determent by the url. For example /api/animals.cat/1 or /api/animals.zoo/1 etc....

Comment: Then you'll need to define a handler for each concrete model, unfortunately. You should be able to define it once and then subclass it for each model.